# Infinite Background Position Animation - jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, infinite

I'm wondering how to make infinite animation on jquery with a plugin "background position animation" i tried to implement setInterval(); but it didn't work, there a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/fyuga/2/

You can see js code like

```
    $('#tile').css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'});
function infinite(){
        $('#tile').animate({backgroundPosition:"-5000px -2500px"},12000);
}
infinite();
setInterval(infinite,12000);
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reset your background initial position after the animation is over inside the animation callback.

## [DEMO jsBin with setTimeout](http://jsbin.com/ejuvef/edit#javascript,html,live)

```
$('#tile').css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'});

var to;

function infinite(){
 to = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#tile').animate({backgroundPosition:"-5000px -2500px"},12000,function(){
      $('#tile').css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'});
      infinite();
    });    
  });
}
infinite();
```

---

**Or your way:**
but I had time ago bad issues using setInterval - causing animations buildups on tab inactivity, but I think this issue is removed from jQuery version 1.6.

Here you go:

## [DEMO jsBin with setInterval](http://jsbin.com/ejuvef/2/edit)

```
    $('#tile').css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'});
function infinite(){

  $('#tile').animate({backgroundPosition:"-5000px -2500px"},12000,function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'});
  });
}
infinite();
setInterval(infinite,12000);
```

Comment: It worked, but you can see it brakes at final position, i would like to make it unstoppable animation, is possible to make this way? If is not possible, i mark your answer

Comment: @Ivan I'll give it a try. I have first to decypher that code :)

Comment: Update: http://jsbin.com/aqotif/3/edit#javascript,html,live   i implemented "linear" at animate(); function it becomes infinite animation, thank you!

Comment: hehe you was faster than me! I was right away to answer that with a link! :) Thanks

Comment: P.S. Before the animate you can add an extra 'security' to be sure your animation are not queued: `.stop(1,1).animate(.....`

Answer (score 4):

or you can use this:

```
function infinite(){
    $('#tile').css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'}).animate({backgroundPosition:"-5000px -2500px"},12000, infinite);
}
infinite();
```

Answer (score 3):

This maybe a late answer, but below is a function that doesn't required the background position plugin.

```
var animate = $('#element');
function loopbackground() {
    animate.css('background-position', '0px 0px');
    $({position_x: 0, position_y: 0}).animate({position_x: -5000, position_y: -2500}, {
        duration: 12000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
            animate.css('background-position', this.position_x+'px '+this.position_y+'px');
        },
        complete: function() {
            loopbackground();
        }
    });
}
loopbackground();
```

View a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kusg5mdg/

---

**Edit....**

I'm back 4 years later to turn the above function into a more reusable bit of code (because why not? **¯\_(ツ)_/¯** )

Reusable, jQuery namespaced function:

```
$.fn.loopBackground = function(options = {}) {
  options = $.extend({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    duration: 300,
    easing: 'linear'
  }, options);

  var $this = $(this);

  function loop() {
    $this.css('background-position', '0px 0px');
    $({ x: 0, y: 0 }).animate({ x: options.x, y: options.y }, {
      duration: options.duration,
      easing: options.easing,
      step: function() {
        $this.css('background-position', this.x+'px '+this.y+'px');
      },
      complete: function() {
        loop();
      }
    })
  }

  loop();
};
```

Usage:

```
$('#title').loopBackground({
  x: -5000,
  y: -2500,
  duration: 30000,
  easing: 'linear' // Optional https://jqueryui.com/easing/
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmvpu06f/